# Return Data provider type Object[] from a Hashmap of <String, List<String>>

Tags: java, testng

I have a Hashmap that has multiple  pair. 
As an example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
{name}- key
{abc, dfc, ghj}- values
{address}- key
{ghj,uio,opd}-values
```

As per TestNg, i want this map to be used in DataProvider annotation and return me an Object[][] which can be used further in the Test in the following manner:

`{{"name,abc"},{"name,dfc"}....}`

Apologies for not mentioning the solution i tried, here it goes:

```
String[] keys = new String[map.size()];
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> values = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            keys[index] = mapEntry.getKey();
            values[index] = mapEntry.getValue();
            index++;
        }
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? It doesn't seem that you have tried something yourself. Please read this: How to create a [mre]

Comment: Please show an example for a possible solution. This is a pretty trivial algorithm

Comment: Just gave my try solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper-class:

```
private class Pair {
  public String key, value;
}
```

your code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList();
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
{
  for(String value : entry.getValue())
  {
    Pair newPair = new Pair();
    newPair.key = entry.getKey();
    newPair.value = value;
    pairs.add(newPair);
  }
}
```